# Uploading Wordpress site from localhost to test on server, css not working

Tags: css, database, wordpress, export

My site was working fine on localhost, but when I upload the site and to test it on this domain - 101share.co.uk - it seems like the stylesheets aren't being loaded properly. I'm sure it's something to do with the database, but I'm not sure.

Comment: why would it have anything to do with the database? it's probably more likely a directory problem.

Comment: All of your CSS files are returning "Not Found" in my network panel, maybe you forgot to upload the CSS directory?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you've uploaded all the sub folders?

I took a look at your site...  viewed the source, and picked out one example file that should be included:

http://101share.co.uk/assets/css/bootstrap.css

When I try to view this file, it says the file does not exist.   Make sure when you uploaded your site that you included all folders / subfolders, etc.

Hope that helps...

Comment: All the files are there, if I go to - 101share.co.uk/wp-content/themes/retlehs-roots-16aad54/assets/… - Then I find the file. but I'm not sure why it isn't looking there for the links files automatically. is there somewhere in the php or database I can change it so that it adds the necessary wp-content and the theme folders etc? –

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It's that the roots theme tries to rewrite your urls in a way that Apache doesn't agree with.

If you comment out these lines under "config.php" it will work.

```
add_theme_support('root-relative-urls');    // Enable relative URLs
add_theme_support('rewrites');              // Enable URL rewrites
```